# Using Threading.Tasks in PowerShell - unexpected results sometimes

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I have a script which contains a function which uses Tasks to scan a range of IPs and when using it on my laptop (Windows 10 x64 with Powershell 5.1.18362.1110), it seems to run fast and relaible.

```
function Test-ConnectionAsync {
    # Uses Async function to check which hosts in a range respond to ICMP
    Param (
        [string[]]$targets,
        [int]$timeout = 1000 # Default timeout of 1 second because high latency is to be expected
    )

    $Task = ForEach ($target in $targets) {
        ([System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping]::new()).SendPingAsync($target,$timeout)
    }

    Try { [Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAll($Task) }
    Catch {}

    $alive = $Task | ForEach-Object {
        If ($_.Result.Status -eq "Success") {
            $_.Result.Address.ToString()
        }
    }

    $alive
}
```

However, I recently started testing this on a Server 2012 system (Powershell 5.1.14409.1018) and sometimes the returned list contains duplicate entries (have not had this happen on my laptop). When changing the code so that it always returns an IP (removing the "If ($_.Result.Status -eq "Success")"), I noticed the following output:

```
10.14.165.1
10.14.165.2
0.0.0.0
...
0.0.0.0
10.14.165.126
10.14.165.2
0.0.0.0
...
```

I'm scanning the range 10.14.164.1 - 10.14.165.254 here and the row below 10.14.165.126 should either contain 10.14.165.127 if it responds or 0.0.0.0 if it doesn't.
But the row is a duplicate 10.14.165.2 entry? Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Edit - calling the function:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
$iplist = [List[string]]::new()
...
$octets = $store.SubnetBO.Split(".")
$prefix = "{0}.{1}" -f $octets[0], $octets[1]
[int]$firstoctet3 = $octets[2]
$lastoctet3 = $firstoctet3 + $store.SubnetSize - 1

$iplist.AddRange([string[]]($firstoctet3..$lastoctet3 | ForEach-Object {$octet3 = $_; 1..254 | ForEach-Object {"$prefix.$octet3.$_"}}))
$aliveips = Test-ConnectionAsync $iplist
```

Comment: You don't show how you define the `$Targets` where the problem most likely lies. Please add the part that invokes the 'Test-ConnectionAsync' function.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It's Generic.List<T>, added the code for clarity. I'm certain $iplist doesn't contain duplicates. I've tested that by having $iplist and $aliveips side-by-side and when $iplist[$i] is "10.14.165.126", the correspondig entry $aliveips[$i] contains "10.14.165.2"